# Blender texture painting dosen't look right

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

When I try to paint my model, it is pretty difficult to paint a straight line. 
What I have done so far, is selecting the faces I want to paint, but the result is pretty bad. It is actually terrible.

My image is **2048 x 2048**, but it might not be enough?
How do you suggest to get rid of these chopped edges?

[image]

Best regards

Comment: Most likely a UV map issue. Try re unwrapping your object with a better UV layout

Comment: you could also draw in your UV Image editor to make a border around you UV edges